# Dom load hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, scripting

Iv'd been looking for this for a while found it once but cant find it agian, in which order does the different things get loaded in the DOM??

like css, html, scripts and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same order they appear in the page

Deferred loading  like :  `document.onreadystatechange` , `window.load` , `defer` attritube ( for script tag)  , injected html  (async) --won't .

the OP asked about the order they loaded in the dom.

once the browser sees  :

```
<img class="a"/>
<img class="b"/>
<img class="c"/>
```

he doesnt care if src is 900 mb or 1 k.

this is the order which will be loaded in the dom.

again ( not talking about defere).

http://jsbin.com/uyocaq/2/edit

Comment: Can you text it out like a list, html then css then and so on

Comment: i **DIDNT** say it is the order.  the items will be loaded the _same_ order they appear **UNLESS deffered commands exists** .

Comment: @Simon It's not a list. You cannot depend on a particular loading order.

Comment: changed to (document.readyState) . and again, the order they appear in the page - it is the order where the dom tree wil be built. and im not talking about defered items ( again);

Comment: i just tought that like html was loaded first then styled by css and last you load your scripts to manipulate the content?